# trying to find the continued students from one year to the next using joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to find the student record from 2006 that returned in 2007. I have a file for 2006 and a file for 2007. I have the following query but not sure if I am using the right join. Also should it be where File2006.ENTRY CODE = 'CONT' or File2007.ENTRY CODE = 'CONT'

'CONT' means the student continued from 2006 to 2007

```
SELECT * 
FROM File2006 inner join File2007 ON File2006.StudentID = File2007.StudentID
WHERE File2006.ENTRY CODE = 'CONT'
```

Comment: If you're after ONLY students who were in 2006 and 2007, you don't need the where clause.  The inner join will only return students who are in both (thus cont).  If you're after students who have RETURNED in 2007 regardless if they are in the 2006 file or not, then you need to change the join to a `right join` (include all records from 2007 and only those that match in 2006) and use File2007.EntryCode.  If you're after anyone who continued in either 2006 or 2007, then you need to use a FULL outer join and have a where clause of `File2006.EntryCode = 'CONT' OR File2007.EntryCode = 'CONT'`

Answer (score 1):

No, I don' think you need to use where clause here. As `Inner join` will returns the common students of both years

```
SELECT * FROM
File2006 inner join File2007 ON File2006.StudentID = File2007.StudentID
```

if *'CONT' means the student continued from 2006 to 2007*
then why don't use simple select query to fetch those students who have `code='CONT'`

```
SELECT * FROM File2007.ENTRYCODE = 'CONT'
```

Comment: well, there are students that continued from years before 2006

Comment: So can students directly goes from 2005 --> 2007 without going to 2006?

Comment: yes, some students take a year or a semester break. So I am not sure if it would be WHERE File2006. ENTRY CODE = 'CONT' or File2007. ENTRY CODE = 'CONT'

Comment: So it all depends on your logic of `CONT` value. But for safer side go with inner join. it will return you the common students

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   file2006 f6
WHERE EXISTS
(
   SELECT 1 FROM file2007 f7 
   WHERE f6.studentid = f7.studentid 
   AND ( f6.entry_code = 'CONT' OR f7.entry_code = 'CONT' )
)
```